# How can you circumvent Windows's 260 chars filepath in Dropbox?

Tags: windows-7, windows, ntfs, file-management, dropbox

[Dropbox says](https://www.dropbox.com/help/145/en) it's limited by [Windows's 260 chars file path limitation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247.aspx). But almost all Windows programs we use work properly with longer filepaths, so it not a Windows problem after all. Is there any way to circumvent this dropbox limitation ?

Answer (score 0):

If the application doesn't support the `\\?\` prefix to support unicode, [paths in Windows are limited to `MAX_PATH`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#maxpath).

Ask the Dropbox Developers to fix it in a new version.